# No data sapecified error when I want to print data in function on jqplot

Tags: php, ajax, jqplot

I am working on a project for graph print.

I call data by ajax and it gives data but when I want to use it.
console gives error **no data specified .**

```
function ajax_call(){

        $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"ajax_process.php",
         data:{curr:curr},
          success: function(result) {     
            //  alert(result);
           $(".output").html(result);
          // global_value=new Array();
          // global_value=[1.23231,1.23231,1.32311,1.43421,1.34531,1.2313,1.1234,1.232,1.1121,1.431];
          global_value=result;
           alert(result);
            show_graph(result);
      }
     });

   }


 function show_graph(global_value){   

   alert("GB"+global_value);
...// CODE

}
```

When I want to print result it gives error but global value which is static not gives error.  I want to use result data . Thanks !!

Comment: What if you `console.log(result);` in your `success` function? What console says? I think, the `global_value` with static value is works, because your syntax is right, but not work, when using `ajax_process.php` because that returns nothing or mallformed data. what is your `axax_process.php` does exactly?

Comment: yes , exactly i the process gives a string and i used it as a array  so i face error